# I keep getting denied for high utilization

Tags: united-states, credit

The last 2-3 years, I have been using a student credit card, and have not had a job. I am a student, and I do freelance work. Before college, my mother gave me a credit card underneath her account to use for food and what not. The problem is, she has bad utilization. My own student credit card, I have no problems with. I see on CreditKarma that my utilization is really high, and I have not used my student cc for the past 2 years (maybe once or twice). I asked my mother to take me off her account, and it has been roughly a year since. What can I do? I feel like I am getting penalized for my mother's poor utilization! If I knew anything about credit cards when I was in high school, I would not have accepted her credit card.

Comment: What exactly is on your credit report? Does your mother's card appear there? You should grab the credit report and take a look exactly what's there, you can get one for free once a year from each of the credit agencies.

Comment: You should also be able to get a free copy of your credit report with each denial. You should list the reasons for denial along with what he credit report shows in that regard.

Comment: If you are being denied for high utilization but you do not have high utilization then this is a red flag for potential identity theft.  As the others have said get a copy of your credit report.  If it is just your mothers habits reflecting on you then you can correct easily.  But you might find unexpected accounts there that are caused by identity theft.  My brother-in-law's mother opened up several charge accounts in his name because he had credit and she did not.  She made payments but kept utilization high just like with her own.  I am not saying your mother did that but take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people had suggested me to remove myself from my parent's credit card account. My response to them is, I had already removed myself from it, for almost a year! Read the question!

Here's what I did everyone. You can call the credit bureaus and dispute the utilization. You can tell them you were not liable for the usage, and they will investigate and remove it. I got it cleared up with Transunion, and now I am going to call Experian and Equifax to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If your mother gave you a card under her account, call that Credit Card company up and tell them to remove you from the account.  Then your mother's bad credit habits will stop reflecting on you going forward and over time your score will heal.

Answer (score 0):

"I feel like I am getting penalized for my mother's poor utilization"

You are.  This is the danger of joint accounts; everyone on the account is responsible, therefore everyone on the account gets penalized for poor behavior.

A safer method to use is to add an "authorized user," in which case that person is allowed to have a card in their name, but the card is only reported under the responsible party.  This is what your mother probably should have done, unless she wanted to help you build your credit (in which case her high utilization had the opposite effect for you).

Another example of when this can occur is if you co-sign for a loan for someone who skips out on it; it doesn't matter that the other person is the one who stopped making payments, by co-signing you are agreeing to be held responsible if the account becomes delinquent.

Answer (score 0):

could you find out if the card you are using actually has you as an "authorized user" or the other way around with your mother?

This can only happen if your credit lines are joined - which seems likely since you got a card without a job at such an early age.